# Storyboard c# animation

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-4.0, storyboard

Well, i want house image to rotate from `-5°` to `5°` and i wrote the following code

```
        Duration duration2 = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        Storyboard sb2 = new Storyboard();
        sb2.Duration = duration2;

        DoubleAnimation da2 = new DoubleAnimation();
        da2.Duration = duration2;

        sb2.Children.Add(da2);

        RotateTransform rt2 = new RotateTransform();

        Storyboard.SetTarget(da2, rt2);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da2, new PropertyPath("Angle"));
        da2.From = 5;
        da2.To = -5;

        HouseImg.RenderTransform = rt2;
        HouseImg.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

        sb2.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        sb2.Begin();
```

But when it ends it goes rapidly to the beginning(`5°`) and what i want is to animate that  also. 
So to conclude: i want to animate from `5°` to `-5°` AND from `-5°` to `5°` also.

Tnx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`AutoReverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to `true`.

```
sb2.AutoReverse = true;
```